# Container (canvas) over HTML5 Video

Tags: html, video, canvas, containers, kineticjs

When using HTML5 Canvas I can use the following to set the Canvas over my HTML5 video.

```
<video id ="video1" width="320" height="300"  controls="controls" style="position:absolute; top: 10; left: 10;" >

<canvas id="canvas3" width="320" height="240" style="position:absolute; top: 10; left: 10;" >
</canvas>
```

How can I do the same thing using KineticJS? I don't see an option for setting position of the container (canvas) with KinetcJS.

I have the following:

```
var myStage = new Kinetic.Stage(canvas3, 100);
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          width: 320,
          height: 240
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

From the KineticJS documentation, the [`Kinetic.Stage`](http://www.kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Stage.php) borrows the [`setAbsolutePosition`](http://www.kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Node.php#setAbsolutePosition) from `Kinetic.Node`. You can use that to set the node's x and y positions.

[Test demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wGbxc/). Use the WebKit console to see that the video element and the canvas are in the same place.